# Control for multiple confounding categorical variables using regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data, controlling-for-a-variable

Assume I have a `x` and `y`-matrix (input and outcome) as follows:

```
x: facility gender ... | y: length_of_stay
         A      M  ... |                3
         B      F  ... |               12 
         A      F  ... |                4 
         C      M  ... |                3 
         C      F  ... |                6 
         A      M  ... |                9
```

`y` has only one dimension.  `x` has many dimensions (`facility`, `gender` and others not of interest).  `facility` and `gender` are categorical.  `x` and `y` are arbitrary length, but the same length.  Assume that I intend to do analysis on dimensions other than `facility` and `gender`, and assume that `facility` and `gender` are confounding variables.

**How do I adjust `length_of_stay` so that it is controlled for `facility` and `gender`?**

I believe that the answer is to do multiple regression between `facility`, `gender`, and `length of stay`.  However, I'm fuzzy on the details of creating the dummy variables (how do I avoid the dummy variable trap when I have an intercept at the origin, and how do I avoid the dummy variable trap when I don't have an intercept at the origin?).  I'm also fuzzy on how to use the betas after completing multiple regression to adjust `length_of_stay`.

Answer (score 2):

1. How many levels are there of facility and gender?
2. What program are you using? If you use R and *set facility and gender* `as.factor()`, then the basic `lm()` function will create dummy codes for you, with the reference category being the first alphabetically (in this case, `A`).
3. The code is as simple as: `lm(length_of_stay ~ facility + gender, data=df)`, where `df` is the data frame that includes *both* of the `x` and `y` matrices.
4. The coefficients can be interpreted as: for `facility`, the difference between the reference category and other categories *after controlling for gender.* For gender (making the assumption that we are sticking to the gender binary), the coefficient would represent the difference between male and female *after controlling for facility.*